# What is this syntax: "Component.For<IOutput>()"?

Tags: .net, syntax, generics

I'm finding code examples all over the place in IoC and DI discussions that use `<` and `>` in their syntax, usually at the end of what looks like a method call.

Can someone

1. Tell me what language this is, and
2. Explain this syntax enough to help me understand the code examples, so I can make sure I understand the underlying principles.

Comment: I'm coming at this most familiar with PHP and Python, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are part of the generics support in the framework.  They allow you to specify a type as part of the method (or class).  They are referred to as type parameters.

For instance you can have a strongly typed list, which relies upon you telling it what type it should accept:

```
List<string> myList;
```

Allows it to accept types of `string` in the `Add` function.  The class definition for this would look *something* like:

```
public class List<T>
{ 
    public void Add(T item) 
    {

    }
}
```

When you created the List you told it to expect a type of `string`.  This is the type parameter `T` in the above class.  In the method `Add` it expects an instance of type `T` (in this instance a string).  Which means when you call `Add` on a `List<string>`, `Add` expects a `string` to be supplied.

Similarly if you created:

```
List<bool> myOtherList;
```

The `Add` method would expect a `bool` parameter not a `string` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The angle brackets are used to denote the type to use. It ensures compile time safety. This is the syntax used for generics (c#).

Answer (score 1):

1.) The language looks like C#, but without reference/context I can't be 100% sure.

2.) Assuming C#, this syntax is used with [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, I suspected it was C#, but I wasn't sure.